# UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.DisplayName) returns null

Tags: c#, .net

Not sure why this happens but when I run this code it works on one server but not on another.

Both servers return a correct found.DisplayName however only one server returns a value for oUserPrincipal the other returns a null value.

Line of error:

```
       UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.DisplayName) returns null


        dynamic config = _getExpandoFromXml("config.xml");

        PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, config.activeDirectory.sDomain, config.activeDirectory.sDefaultOU,config.mailServer.user, config.mailServer.pass);
        UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(ctx);

        PrincipalSearcher search = new PrincipalSearcher(user);
        Console.WriteLine("before foreach");
        foreach (Principal found in search.FindAll())
        {
            try{
                if (found.DisplayName == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("found.Dispalyname is null");
                }
                else
                {    
                    Console.Write("Dispalyname: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(found.DisplayName);
                }
                UserPrincipal oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.DisplayName);
                Console.Write("looking for user: ");
                Console.WriteLine(found.DisplayName);
                Console.WriteLine("after findbyidentiy");
                if (oUserPrincipal == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("oUserPrinciapal is null");
                }
                if (oUserPrincipal.LastPasswordSet == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("lastpasswordset is null");
                }
                DateTime? dateOrNull = oUserPrincipal.LastPasswordSet;
                Console.WriteLine("after LastPasswordSet");
```

Comment: FindByIdentity wants the SAMAccountName.  DisplayName could be the same, or it may not be depending how the user was created.  Try UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.SamAccountName);

Comment: Will do. Trying it tomorrow, ill let you how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FindByIdentity can only search on a handful of properties.  These are "any format that is contained in the [IdentityType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb356425.aspx) enumeration".

Name is a valid option but DisplayName is not listed so you will probably get results where the DisplayName and Name happen to be the same and it will fail otherwise.

Using:

```
var oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.Name);
```

or

```
var oUserPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, found.SamAccountName);
```

should work.

There is also a [three parameter version of FindByIdentity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344891.aspx) that allows you to specify the property you would like to search on.

Comment: Nick, have any idea on this question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15416777/pwdlastset-showing-up-on-one-server-a-but-not-on-server-b-even-though-its-ther

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I found the issue was that it wasn't connecting to the AD server.  If I hovered over `oPrincipalContext`, its property of `ConnectedServer` showed that it threw an exception of type `System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException`.  If this happens, a restart of services on the Domain Controller should work.  We found it can happen during high-login times, since we only have 1 DC on our dev network.

[image]