# pwdLastSet showing up on one server A but not on server B, even though it's there

Tags: .net, active-directory

pwdLastSet is not being returned in my code below on server B. On Server B the users are created by "Crowd" i'm guessing via LDAP. I can see the field when I examine the user in AD Manger, but when I try to get pwdLastSet on Server B through code it doesn't work. However it all works on server A where I create the users through AD.

I have also tried "LastPasswordSet" through the UserPrincipal object.

```
private static DateTime DateTest(string userName)
   {
       userName = userName.Trim();
       DateTime hacked;
       using (DirectorySearcher ds = new DirectorySearcher())
       {
           ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;
           ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
           ds.PropertiesToLoad.Add("pwdLastSet");
           ds.PageSize = 1;
           ds.ServerPageTimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
           ds.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectCategory=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", userName);

           SearchResult sr = ds.FindOne();
           //hacked = DateTime.FromFileTime((long)sr.Properties["pwdLastSet"][0]);

            IDictionaryEnumerator e = sr.Properties.GetEnumerator();
           while (e.MoveNext())
           {
               //if (typeof(ResultPropertyCollection) == e.Key.GetType())
               //{
               //    foreach (var item in (ResultPropertyCollection)e.Key)
               //    {
               //        Console.WriteLine(e);
               //    }

               //}
               Console.Write(e.Key);
               Console.Write(" : ");

               foreach (var item in (ResultPropertyValueCollection)e.Value)
               {
                   Console.WriteLine(item);
               }
           }
       }

       return DateTime.Now;
   }
```

Comment: Is the pwdLastSet property missing entirely from the SearchResult object or is the property there but coming up null or as a default datetime?

Comment: The other thing to check, if you have primary and secondary domain controllers, is if your code is connecting to a domain controller that hasn't had the pwdLastSet value replicated to it yet.  The DirectorySearch constructor takes a path argument which will allow you to specify the domain controller it connects to.

Comment: It is not showing up at all, I will check to make sure it is the primary domain controller.

Comment: Thanks again for the help on the last few questions Nick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite the fact that my login has enterprise/domain admin group membership this was still not working when I executed it.

However when I right clicked the console app and ran it as administrator, it worked like a charm. Garr!

Comment: When setting up your DirectorySearcher you can specify a searchRoot parameter which can be given a path, username and password.  If you run this with the username and password of an AD admin do you see the property?